# How to avoid a huge list of JavaFX coordinate translations (caused by UI responses)

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm making a ScalaFX (but use of Scala is irrelevant here) application with a user interface similar to i.e. Google maps. There's panning and zooming.

For each such change of the user's viewpoint, I add a transform into a Group's `.transforms`.

```
transforms += new Translate( dx, dy )
```

or

```
transforms += new Scale( 1/f,1/f, cx, cy )
```

This seems like the only way to affect transformations (apart from `translateXYZ`, `layoutXYZ`, which I'm ignoring), and it works.

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) say this:

> Multiple transformations may be applied to a node by specifying an
>   ordered chain of transforms. The order in which the transforms are
>   applied is defined by the ObservableList specified in the transforms
>   variable.

Doesn't this imply that there's a list (even, an observable list) of potentially hundreds or thousands of entries long?

If so, I would like to flatten the list occasionally. Tried calling `.localToSceneTransoform` and `.localToParentTransform` for this (thinking I'd then set the .transforms with the received overall affine matrix). That *crashed* the JVM.

Am I doing something wrong here, or should I just stop caring about the list growing, well, indefinately?

Can provide a short ScalaFX sample code to highlight all this (including the crash). Please ask.

System: OS X, JVM 7u10

Comment: Instead of constantly adding transforms, can't you combine the new transform with the previous one? So you always have only one transform of each type.

Comment: Yes, I did that but the even better approach is utilizing the Observable behaviour of the transform objects (i.e. '.x' is a DoubleProperty).

Answer (score 1):

It took a while to get to the 'thinking' of JavaFX transformations. The idea is that one makes a list of transforms, and changes the Observable parameters of those transforms. This takes away the need to constantly add more and more transforms to the list.

This is actually a very cute way of handling it. Sadly it's not obvious from any of the docs I've read (reason to leave this entry in SO me thinks).

The necessary code is something like:

```
private val panTrans = new Translate(0,0)

transforms = 
  panTrans ::
  Nil

...

panTrans.x = panTrans.x() + dx
panTrans.y = panTrans.y() + dy
```

I think it will be obvious from here.

Comment: But wait! Rotating about the origin and then translating dx and dy gives a different result than translating by dx and dy and then rotating about the origin. So even if I have one of each kind of Transform in the list and mutate them, a single instance of each kind of Transform might not be sufficient to handle the cases. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's been a while since I was at this. But essentially any transform turns out into a generic matrix operation (matrix multiplication). So it might be better to think of the rotations etc. as yet-another-generic-matrix to be multiplied to the current generic transform.

Answer (score 0):

The original question asked:

> Doesn't this imply that there's a list (even, an observable list) of potentially hundreds or thousands of entries long?

Yes that's correct.

> If so, I would like to flatten the list occasionally.

If you want to flatten the list then in most cases you can do so like this:

```
Transform aggregate = myGroup.getLocalToSceneTransform();
myGroup.getTransforms().clear();
myGroup.getTransforms().add(aggregate);
```

A bit clunky but it works.

**HOWEVER** as you point out a neater approach is to add a *single* transform to the observable list of the `Node` and keep updating it.

In cases where you need to concatenate to the the existing transform use an `Affine` ([javafx.scene.transform.Affine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Affine.html)) because it has ‘append()’ methods. For example:

```
Affine affine = new Affine();
myGroup.getTransforms().add(affine);

// then in your event handler or loop
affine.append(myNewTransform);
```